# How to change row names of a DTM when writing to .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, tm, topic-modeling

I have a large set of documents stored in a folder. I used these documents for text mining, using the tm package. I got all the way to topic modeling and want to write some results to a csv file. However, when doing this, the names of the documents are represented like this: character(0).

I want to have the names of the documents as they are stored in my folder. This is the code I use (relevant steps shown only):

```
my_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory, pattern = ".pdf"), 
                 readerControl = list(reader = readPDF, language = "dutch"))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(my_corpus)
library(topicmodels)
ldaOut <- LDA(dtm, k, method = "Gibbs")
ldaOut.topics <- as.matrix(topics(ldaOut))
write.csv(ldaOut.topics, file = paste("LDAGibbs", k, "CorpusToTopics.csv"))
```

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I assume it's a basic code in R that I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird how you loose the document names. I don't seem to be able to reproduce this error and I have a lot of different folders with pdf's and loads of different naming conventions.

Check the result of `dtm$dimnames$Docs` just when you created the dtm. If this results in `charactor(0)`, you can do the following to get the document names into the document term matrix.

```
pdf_names <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".pdf")
dtm$dimnames$Docs <- pdf_names
```

Comment: once again, thank you. It's indeed weird. I work with 'protected' pdf's, so maybe that's a possible reason, but I'm just guessing. Anyway, now there is a solution if anyone encounters the same problem.